# Simple Framework Mechanics

Tags: oop, php

I'm building a simple framework and hoping it will help me better understand OOP. Well, I've come across my first hurdle.

I'm naturally using MVC pattern and I have a user model. I then have a 'table' which manages the collection of user objects. I have an abstract model and table. Similar to Zend Framework layout.

Anyway, I'm now wondering what is the best way to execute a query? I have a database object which manages the database layer. Currently using mysqli object.

Trouble is my connection is a member of my application object, how do I access that from within my table object to execute a query? I obviously can't create a new object because that will connect to the database again. I need to reuse this same db object.

Any ideas? I understand if this isn't optimal design. Right now I'm just looking for advice.

---

**Edit:** Should I just use Doctrine?

Comment: Create a `getConnection()` method in your application object that returns the connection. When you create the table object, send it a reference to the application object. This seems pretty basic but perhaps I'm not understanding the question right.

Comment: how would I then access the application object from the table object? I would have to either pass the application object through when I instantiate a table object which is definitely wrong, or declare the application object global? Maybe I'm missing something. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why would passing the application object to the table object constructor be wrong?

Comment: I don't see how I'm interfering with others answering. I'm just trying to help, maybe I'm not understanding your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doctrine or not?

If your intention is to learn how to write SQL Queries and to create something for your own, use mysqli or PDO.

If you would like to learn how to use a real object oriented database layer, use doctrine. With 3 pages tutorial, you can do the most general things. However some very special cases are better coded in raw sql than with doctrine. But if you know how to do things with doctrine it is a very useful library and you end up writing better, consistenter, more readabler and extensiabler (:-)) code.

Answer (score 1):

you should add such dependencies in constructor.

You are able to use a static db object too, but especially for a framework like project this will get you to hell, if you try to add unit-tests or you want to refactor.

In named Patterns, you want to use dependency injection for this